# Matlab cannot find shared library on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, matlab, mex

I have some code that calls a Mex function. I compiled the Mex function and try to invoke the code, and get this error:

```
Invalid MEX-file '/v/filer4b/v41q001/evouga/projects/gptoolbox/mex/selfintersect.mexa64': libboost_thread.so.1.54.0: cannot open
shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But that library is definitely on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

```
>> getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')

ans =

/lusr/opt/boost-1.54/lib:/v/filer4b/software/matlab-r2014a/sys/os/glnxa64:/v/filer4b/software/matlab-r2014a/bin/glnxa64:/v/filer4b/software/matlab-r2014a/extern/lib/glnxa64:/v/filer4b/software/matlab-r2014a/runtime/glnxa64:/v/filer4b/software/matlab-r2014a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/v/filer4b/software/matlab-r2014a/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

And I know "No such file or directory" can sometimes mean "the file exists just fine, but is built for the wrong architecture, and for whatever reason we're going to print a blatant lie as the error message." But when I check

```
>> !file /lusr/opt/boost-1.54/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0
/lusr/opt/boost-1.54/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x9ebc964acececa3632afe12b3526fe38f5b8c3eb, not stripped
```

it seems to be fine: a 64-bit library that matches the 64-bit .mexa64 file.

```
>> !file /v/filer4b/v41q001/evouga/projects/gptoolbox/mex/selfintersect.mexa64
/v/filer4b/v41q001/evouga/projects/gptoolbox/mex/selfintersect.mexa64: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

What should I do next to try to figure out what's going on?

Comment: What does `ldd` say about the file from within MATLAB?

Comment: matlab probably opens the library with **dlopen(3)** and doesn't use the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  Look at matlab documentation for integrating modules into matlab for this issue.